# Custom map drawing ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to modify IOS MKMapView such that I want all continents to be of my own colour such as green colour and I want to include only continents in map (water area should be hidden or transparent). Also when I tap on particular region, then I should be able to retrieve the latitude and longitude after customising ( mainly focussing on fetching country info only ). Please suggest me any methods to implement this.
Thank You.